# jQuery/Javascript: tidy html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tidy

i'm got a little html-wysiwyg editor in my cms and was wondering - is there a good script for tidying up html client-side? i'm mainly struggling with html that's pasted from winword.
maybe some regex would help already.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your wysiwyg editos TinyMCE? If so it has plugin to clean up code pasted from word.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting from WORD into a WYSIWYG editor is usually a bad idea. There are editors that try to clean this up, but none of them do a perfect job. FCK editor has a strip-WORD feature, but it's not fool-proof.

WORD does some dumb things like: `<bold>some <bold></bold> words</bold>`, which are difficult for programs to detect and fix. You end up with all kinds of superfluous mark-up that can mess things up.

The only safe bet is to strip out ALL of the markup (i.e. make it plain text) and allow the user to fix it up in the editor.

Comment: +1: The problem is, Word C&P gives you all this tag soup that you can't really convert to standard HTML/CSS. FONT tags especially should have died a horrible death long ago, but there they are, and the bandage really sticks to the wound. In the long run it's simpler and cleaner, as Diodeus says, to take it down to the bare metal and start over.